# Batch file that runs another batch file, and reopens it when it closes

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that:
1. Opens another batch file, or detects when this batch file is open
2. Will reopen this batch file when it closes.
I am completely new to making batch files so I don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: By "open" do you actually mean "run" or open it as a text file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a fairly new to batch, but I'll try to help as much as I can.

you can run a batch file two ways (that I know of)

first you can use the `start` command.

```
start C:\yourfolder\thefolder\batch.bat
```

This will run the bat file in its own window and separately to the original bat file.

You can also use `call`

```
call C:\yourfolder\thefolder\batch.bat
```

This will run the bat file in the same window and finish it before it continues with the rest of the original file.

Detecting a specific batch script opening and reopening it when it closes with another batch script are things I have also looked into and the answer I've found is **maybe** but it will most likely be beyond the scope of a beginner. The reason is that batch files all open as cmd.exe so you can't differentiate with `tasklist`. I've come to the conclusion that you might be able to open a batch, find it's PID and continually check to see if a process with that PID is running, but that's far beyond my abilities.